# Extract string from XML node using Bash script

Tags: xml, bash

I can't seem to find exactly how to do this. I have this XML file

```
<session>
  <translations>
   <translation>
      <inside>198.18.133.1</inside>
      <name>adfs.domain1.com</name>
    </translation>
    <translation>
      <inside>198.18.135.60</inside>
      <name>hds.domain2.com</name>
    </translation>
   </translations>
 </session>
```

and I want to extract the domain from a particular name node based on the string found in the inside node. As you can see I have multiple name and inside nodes.  With the following Bash file I can extract the first instance of name

```
#!/bin/bash
domain="$(echo "cat /session/translations/translation/name/text()" | xmllint --nocdata --shell session.xml | sed '1d;$d')"
domain="${domain:5}"
printf '%s\n' "Domain is: $domain"
```

This will give me domain1.com.

Sometimes I could have more translations or less and they aren't always in the same order.  So I need a way to pull the name IF the inside node matches 198.18.133.1 or pull the name IF the inside node matches 198.18.135.60, etc.

Comment: Have you considered XSLT? You can do it with Java SE and Saxonica HE.

Comment: @jeff6times7, there's no need for a JVM -- every modern Linux distro (and MacOS) ships with `xsltproc`. Maybe if you needed something newer than 1.0, but this query doesn't need a modern version of the standard.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Are you sure Jason's using linux?

Comment: Even if it's not Linux, it's something that ships with bash, and that narrows it down enough. xsltproc is pretty much ubiquitous these days -- it's widely used for compiling documentation to HTML at build time. If you have a recent (last-15-years) UNIX-family system with a compiler/development toolchain, it's more more common to not have a JVM than to not have xsltproc.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Then it's hopefully an easy decision based upon the long-term requirements. If the user's *not* headed towards a complicated transformation, then XSLT is overkill.

Comment: Incidentally, XMLStarlet compiles command-line queries down to XSLT -- one can (in the relevant usage modes) ask it to output an XSLT template which will perform the same operation given on the command line.

Comment: BTW, I'd suggest `domain=${domain#*.}` to strip off everything up to and including the first period -- that way it'll work the same way if that prefix's length isn't exactly four characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current XPath expression, of:

```xml
/session/translations/translation/name/text()
```

...can easily be changed to:

```xml
/session/translations/translation[inside="198.18.133.1"]/name/text()
```

...to perform the desired filtering.

---

Doing this with XMLStarlet, rather than XMLLint, might look more like:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -m '/session/translations/translation[inside="198.18.133.1"]/name' -v . -n
```

If adding the `-C` argument to the `sel` subcommand, it will emit the XSLT template which it's evaluating under-the-hood, which you could run anywhere with `xsltproc` installed, including systems without XMLStarlet:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:exslt="http://exslt.org/common" version="1.0" extension-element-prefixes="exslt">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="/session/translation/translation[inside=&quot;198.18.133.1&quot;]/name">
      <xsl:call-template name="value-of-template">
        <xsl:with-param name="select" select="."/>
      </xsl:call-template>
      <xsl:value-of select="'&#10;'"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template name="value-of-template">
    <xsl:param name="select"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$select"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="exslt:node-set($select)[position()&gt;1]">
      <xsl:value-of select="'&#10;'"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried to change the XPath expression and it gave me this error. "XPath error : Invalid predicate
/session/translations/translation[inside=198.18.133.1]/name/text()
                                               ^
xmlXPathEval: evaluation failed
/session/translations/translation[inside=198.18.133.1]/name/text(): no such node

Comment: the ^ was under the period after 18 if that helps

Comment: See how it's just `inside=198.18.133.1`, not `inside="198.18.133.1"`, in the error? You don't want to let the shell eat your quotes.

Comment: ...there's a reason I used single quotes on the outside in this answer -- so the double-quotes inside them would be preserved.

Comment: Sweet yes that was it!  Thanks so much for the quick response!  Works like a champ!